# Custom QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, pyqt5, qt5, pyqt, qfilesystemmodel

Создаю `QFileSystemModel`, помещаю в `QTableView` или `QTreeView`, отображается 4 колонки с именем, размером, типом и датой модификации файла.

Как сделать чтобы `QFileSystemModel` изначально имел мною определённое количество колонок с моей определённой информацией для файлов?

Answer (score 1):

Наследовать [QFileSystemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) и переопределить методы `columnCount` и `data` (C++):

```
class MyFileSystemModel: public QFileSystemModel {
public:
    virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override {
        return <Количество колонок для данного родителя (parent)>;
    }

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override {
        // ...
        return <данные для данного index>;
    }
}
```

python

```py
class MyFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        ...
        return <Количество колонок для данного родителя (parent)>

    def data(self, index, role):
        ...
        return <данные для данного index>
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете попробовать поиграться со свойствами QTableView/QTreeView для настройки способа представления модели:

- QTableView/QTreeView ::horizontalHeader() -> QHeaderView:: hideSection(...)/showSection(...), ...
- QTreeView:: isHeaderHidden()/setHeaderHidden(), ...

Это поможет скрыть/отобразить интересующие столбцы.

Для более сложного поведения, вроде добавления своих собственных столбцов к стандартной модели, достаточно написать прокси-модель, которая будет формировать столбцы в дополнение существующим. При таком подходе также можно поиграться с видимостью и порядком следования стандартных столбцов, реализовав мапинг в прокси-модели.